# Magento2 change Tax to VAT

Tags: magento2, tax, localisation

I am trying to change Tax to say **VAT** across the site. I have tried to change the `en_US.csv` file located in **i18n** in my theme, but with no result. Is this changed on database level, and if so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the right place, but presumably you need to use:

```
en_GB.csv
```

if your store is in the UK.

Answer (score 5):

**Magento ver. 2.1.9**

go to here: / vendor / magento / module-tax / view / frontend / layout / checkout_cart_index.xml

find and replace Tax to VAT

and

/ vendor / magento / module-tax / view / frontend / layout / checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Translation files should just be used for translation management, not used a means of changing the semantic meaning of a label.

Comment: Yes, this is the place to start

Comment: Changes to the module-tax file will just be overwritten the next time you update, won't they? Doesn't seem to be a good method to me.

Comment: You shouldnt change the core of magento to do a translation

Answer (score 0):

Perfect 
Thank you

For Australian GST,  file name needs to be added en_AU.csv

add line 
"Tax", "GST"

Answer (score -1):

/public_html/vendor/magento/module-tax/i18n

in folder create file en_GB.csv and write

Tax   VAT