# How can we change Tax text to other text in magento 2.3?

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.4

can we change **Tax** text to other text like "**US 6% Sales Tax**",
in the checkout,

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134727/magento2-change-tax-to-vat Try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy way to follow step and change your text :-

First this file override your theme **`checkout_cart_index.xml`** and change your text

> **`/app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Tax/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/tax</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/checkout/cart/totals/tax</item>
                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">US 6% Sales Tax</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

After you change run below command :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

And Check **`Output :-`**

[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: thanks Mohit Patel, its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Find file

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\checkout\tax.phtml

And find this code

```
<?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

I just commented out the echo part.... and replaced with "Your word".

I know this is not correct way but your work will be done.

Thanks.